# Javacord can't be imported in minecraft plugin

Tags: java, discord, minecraft

How do I make a Minecraft spigot plugin that is at the same time a discord bot? the server thinks that the class `org.javacord.api.DiscordApiBuilder` doesn't exists so cant load the plugin. I use Maven(eclipse)

it says that the `DiscordApiBuilder` class isn't defined, how do I import that jar?

is it possible or i have to change the discord api?
error:

```
Could not load 'plugins\StoneBot.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/javacord/api/DiscordApiBuilder
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:135) ~[spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:329) ~[spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:251) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:291) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:744) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:534) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:646) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:632) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.aM(DedicatedServer.java:353) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.z(DedicatedServer.java:317) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.y(MinecraftServer.java:634) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:537) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_301]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/javacord/api/DiscordApiBuilder
        at adwidu.mainPackage.Main.<init>(Main.java:15) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:76) ~[spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:131) ~[spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.javacord.api.DiscordApiBuilder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:101) ~[spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:86) ~[spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at adwidu.mainPackage.Main.<init>(Main.java:15) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:76) ~[spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:131) ~[spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        ... 14 more
```

Comment: #1 What is your minecraft version and os do you have? #2 Are you developing something or just want to add a plugin to a existent micraft server?

Comment: 1.8
win10
im developing something

Comment: Nice! Is your development a maven based project?

Comment: Yep it is a maven based proyect

Comment: Did you add the dependencies of your new plugin?

Comment: javacord into pom.xml and that spigot thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jar that you imported isn't load on your minecraft server.

To use your dependency, such as it's not a plugin that can be runned by spigot, you have to include it in builded jar.

To do it, you have to add this to your `pom.xml` :

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> 
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Warn:** This will add ALL dependencies in your jar.

To don't include plugin such as spigot, you have to add `<scope>provided</scope>` like this :

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
   <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.17.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: it didn't work (I cant speak english lol)

Comment: Why ? What is the issue ?

Comment: the same thing that happened before, NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: nevermind, just me not understanding